# activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-server-2008, odbc, dsn

I am trying to connect to SQL Server from a Ruby on Rails Application.

I installed the gem `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` and realized from tutorials that I will need a DSN in order to connect to it.

I have 3 questions;

1. Do I need to install the gem `ruby-odbc` in order for this sqlserver gem to work?
2. Are there any alternative ways of connecting to the db without using a DSN?
3. Can I do scaffolding with RoR and SQL Server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using TinyTDS (not ODBC) to connect to SQL Server. Have you looked at the [project page on github](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter) and [what they recommend on the wiki](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Using-TinyTds)?

We even bundle prebuilt native gems for windows so they do not have to install FreeTDS too.

Comment: I have the same problem in windows 10 , i am using ruby 2.4 and rails 5.1.2. i have this error: LoadError: cannot load such file -- tiny_tds/tiny_tds

LoadError: 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/rubyinstaller-2.4.1-1-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/tiny_tds-1.3.0-x64-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds/2
.4/tiny_tds.so

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

1. The sql-adapter is part of the Rails installation.
2. There might be, but why not use dsn unless you can't
3. Can't help you there, but if you use ActiveRecord as a base class, the contents of the database datastream are inferred from the metadata returned from the database.

See my response to the following question for some setup help:

[Add SQL 2014 support to activerecord-sqlserver-adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301852/add-sql-2014-support-to-activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/54136113#54136113)